# How to check if mysql query was successful using C++

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm using a C++ interpreter ([ROOT](https://root.cern/), the CERN framework) to access several mySQL tables in a loop. Every time I query a table that doesn't exist, the program quits on me:

```
for (int run = 19000; run < 22000; run ++) {
    s << run;
    num = s.str();
    schema = "run_0"+num+"_R007";
    s.str("");

    //creating our query
    query = "select distinct *whatever* from "+schema+".kTrack;";
    res = conPtr->Query(query);
    conPtr->Close();
    //Here is where I don't know what to do:
    if (*success*) {
        do stuff
    }
    else {
        do stuff
    }
}
```

I don't have a problem if the table returns 0 rows, I have a problem if the table doesn't exist.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you try catching exceptions?

Comment: I had thought of that, but I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution using the mySQL connection and result objects

Comment: "I'm using a C++ interpreter" - *Really*? Which one? C++ is a really hard language to write an interpreter for. I've seen some C++98 interpreters that implemented most (but never all) of the language - never any one that implemented C++11 or later. Genuinely currious here; what interpreter are you using?

Comment: @JesperJuhl As I mentioned, I am using ROOT. Not going to lie, it's pretty awful to work with most of the time, but it's used a lot in high energy physics.

Comment: @Evan - have you got a link to this ROOT C++ interpretor?

Comment: @JesperJuhl https://root.cern/
www.google.com is a great resource for finding these sorts of things. Ask.com is decent, but has certainly fallen off recently.

Comment: Please show the types for `res` and for `conPtr`. There's no telling how to make sense of it without this. A possibility is `if ( NULL != res ) { ... }`

Comment: nitpick, root is as much as C++ interpreter as LLVM is a compiler. the actual interpreter part is just cling https://root.cern.ch/cling (cf stackoverflow tag [cling]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `conPtr` is a pointer to a [`TMySQLServer`](https://root.cern.ch/doc/v612/classTMySQLServer.html) object, ROOT's documentation for [`TMySQLServer::Query()`](https://root.cern.ch/doc/v612/classTMySQLServer.html#a0fe44da66b3f0d02dfc9aa14657898f8) says:

> **Returns a pointer to a `TSQLResult` object if successful, 0 otherwise**. The result object must be deleted by the user.

So `Query()` returns a NULL pointer on failure.

Also, since your loop is not re-opening a new DB connection on each iteration, you should not be calling `conPtr->Close()` until after you are done performing queries with it.

Try something more like this:

```
for (int run = 19000; run < 22000; run ++) {
    s << run;
    num = s.str();
    schema = "run_0"+num+"_R007";
    s.str("");

    //creating our query
    query = "select distinct *whatever* from "+schema+".kTrack;";
    res = conPtr->Query(query);
    if (res) {
        // use res as needed...
        delete res;
    }
    else {
        // ...
    }
}
conPtr->Close();
```